# How to run iPython **line** magic from a script?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, ipython-magic

I've found a way to run magic commands, eg

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
```

but how do you run something like `!ls` ?

Specifically, I need this to run a console script at runtime in Google Colab.

I have a library called `dimcli` that needs to create a local credentials file. Normally I'd invoke it like this `!dimcli --init`. However I'd like to run that command automatically each time the library gets loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Think I got it

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic("sx", "ls")
```

See https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/8.16.x/IPython/core/magics/osm.py#L681